# IIS 10 website with hostname served by Default Web Site

Tags: iis, hostname, ip-address, domain-name, iis-10

I have configured some websites in IIS on my Windows VPS.
When I am accessing this subdomain installer.app-wards.com from the server, it's going to the wwwroot folder from Default Web site instead of the physical path I have configured for the web site.

Result when I access http://installer.app-wards.com/ from the server (it should display "Working" instead). Sorry the server is in French
[image]

Default Web Site bindings
[image]

Other web site bindings
[image]

Here you can see the physical path is different than wwwroot, so it's not serving this web site.
[image]

EDIT : here is the output of nslookup installer.app-wards.com
[image]

Comment: Open a command prompt and run `nslookup installer.app-wards.com` and the output should tell what's wrong. Site bindings are there to match the incoming requests a site would like to handle, so every bits of them must match.

Comment: I added the output of the command. We moved to a new server 3 days ago, it is maybe related?

Comment: @LexLi thank you, you gave me the hint. I changed the ip in IIS to use the IPv6 instead of IPv4 and it works! No idea why the IPv4 is not working though

Comment: Better to add both actually

Comment: Is the server running IIS actually on the public IP address, or is it perhaps behind a firewall with NAT in use, so it's actually on an internal IP, for instance 192.168.0.x? Eg, if you run `ipconfig` in a cmd prompt on the server, which v4 IP is returned? If it's on an internal IP, you need to configure the v4 host entry in IIS using that internal IP not the public IP, since the server itself doesn't have a binding for the public IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your DNS server has both IPv4 and IPv6 records for this sub domain, the browser seems to send HTTP requests to the IPv6 address of this IIS server. That's why your IPv4 specific site bindings didn't work.

You might add IPv6 specific bindings like you discovered, or simply change the current bindings to associate with All Unassigned.